# CSV writer not writing new JSON values from API call

Tags: python, json, api, csv

I'm trying to save the JSON results of an API call to CSV.  The API is in a for loop where it subtracts a day and re-runs the API to get the price of a Bitcoin.  It's then supposed to save each API call to a row in a CSV but it's currently only saving the last API call.

How can I get it to write a row for each returned API call?

```
import requests
import json
import csv

timestampCurrent = 1550698057
timestampOneWeekAgo = 1550161800
oneDay = 86400

for timestamp in range(timestampCurrent, timestampOneWeekAgo, -oneDay):
    print(timestamp)

    base_url = "https://api.gemini.com/v1/trades/btcusd"
    payload = {'timestamp' : timestamp,
                'limit_trades' : '1'}

    r = requests.get(url = base_url, params = payload)

    time = r.json()

    print(time)

# open a file for writing
bitcoincsv = open('/Users/kanye_west/Desktop/Code/Python/BitcoinTracker/bitcoinyear.csv', 'w')

# create csv writer object
csvwriter = csv.writer(bitcoincsv)

count = 0

for year in time:

    if count == 0:

        header = year.keys()
        csvwriter.writerow(header)
        count += 1

    csvwriter.writerow(year.values())

    bitcoincsv.close()

# append csv results
# save CSV file
```

Comment: Because you're not writing to the file in your loop. The entire loop completes, then you do the write. Either put the values into a list and then `writerows` the data or put the writes inside the loop.

Comment: I'm kinda new to python, do I just indent everything below print(time) to achieve this?

Comment: Put `bitcoincsv = ...` and `csvwriter =` _above_ the `for` loop, indent the `writerow` command but don't close the file in the loop. I'm on a phone sorry.

Comment: Actually, you have two loops so that alone wont be enough i don't think

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
import requests
import csv

URL = 'https://api.gemini.com/v1/trades/btcusd'

TIMESTAMP_CURRENT = 1550698057
TIMESTAMP_ONE_WEEK_AGO = 1550161800
ONE_DAY = 86400


def get_time_slot_data(timestamp):
    r = requests.get(URL, params={'timestamp': timestamp, 'limit_trades': '1'})
    if r.status_code == 200:
        return r.json()


with open('gemini.csv', 'wb') as out:
    headers_written = False
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    for timestamp in range(TIMESTAMP_CURRENT, TIMESTAMP_ONE_WEEK_AGO, -ONE_DAY):
        daily_data = get_time_slot_data(timestamp)
        if not headers_written and daily_data:
            writer.writerow(daily_data[0].keys())
            headers_written = True
        if daily_data:
            for entry in daily_data:
                writer.writerow(entry.values())
```